# Прокрутка к якорю с отступом сверху

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка

При клике на ссылку идет прокрутка страницы к якорю, но на странице также есть фиксированное горизонтальное меню, и получается, что страница прокручивается слишком много.

Как сделать, чтобы прокрутка останавливалась примерно в 100 пикселях от якоря?

Вот код страницы и скрипт:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // = Вешаем событие прокрутки к нужному месту
     //  на все ссылки якорь которых начинается на #
     $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      var target = this.hash,
      $target = $(target);
    
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
       'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 900, 'swing', function () {
       window.location.hash = target;
      });
     });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Плавная навигация на странице | Howtomake</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>  
  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
      <li><a href="#six">Six</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div id="main">
    <h2 id="one">One</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="two">Two</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <h2 id="three">Three</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="four">Four</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="five">Five</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="six">Six</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте так `$target.offset().top - 100`, вместо 100 можно поставить нужное значение в px, вот кусок вашего кода с полной функцией:

```
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 100
 }, 900, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

У меня заработало c

```
scrollTop': $target.offset().top - ($('#nav-container').height()+ 50)
```

Когда убрала строку:

```
function () {window.location.hash = target;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно `$target.offset().top` - (высота меню + 100).
Решение http://jsfiddle.net/gg7hg7m8/

```
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-($('ul').height()+ 100)  
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
    });
```

Регулируя значение в скобочках (100), вы будете регулировать ваш отступ.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот это:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
        && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - ($("#main-header").outerHeight(true)+ 20); //#main-header - заменить на ваш элемент
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Уже есть способ попроще. Есть свойство scroll-margin-top, которое задает высоту отступа, которая используется при скролле к элементу. Работает во всех современных браузерах.

https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-margin-top

```
:target{scroll-margin-top:100px;}
```

Comment: (:target{scroll-margin-top:100px;}) Помойму - это лучший ответ!

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, это избавляет от многих CSS / JS костылей для отступов.

Comment: К сожалению способ не срабатывает, если на странице используется плавный скрол сделанный с помощью JS, а от плавного скрола отказаться сложно)). Казалось бы можно добиться плавного скрола без использования JS, через  `* {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` , но данный способ работает не во всех браузерах. Проще говоря, если не до красоты, то это пожалуй лучший и простой способ добавить отступ. Спасибо!