# Добавление пустого пространства в верхнюю часть страницы после перехода по ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Допустим, у нас есть несколько заголовков с ID, в позицию поторых можно перемещаться через ссылки, а в самом верху висит, перекрывая часть содержимого, менюшка (судя по всему, спозиционированная через `static`). Каждый раз, когда мы кликаем на ссылку, отправляющую к заголовку, то заголовок оказывается спрятанным за менюшку, как показано на рисунке ниже. Меню убрать или ещё что-то сделать с ним не могу, так как просили не вмешиваться в Wordpress-шаблон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал добавить блоку с заголовком и `margin` и `padding` - без толку; всё пустое пространство оказывается выше видимой области страницы.

Какое самое короткое решение Вы можете предложить чтобы при автоматической прокрутки страницы вниз после клика по ссылке увидеть что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно "докрутить" при помощи javascript.

Comment: Якорем является сам заголовок?

Comment: Нет, якорем является контейнер (я на картинке его отметил оранжевым).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, без javascript тут никак и необходимо следующее решение:

```
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 100
 }, 900, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
 });
```

Источник: [Прокрутка к якорю с отступом сверху](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379110)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! А можно Вас попросить показать вариант без знака доллара? Непонятно, что с $target делать. (Дело в том что в Wodpress знаки доллара в JavaScript не допускаются, потому приходится jQeury() использовать вместо упрощённого вызова)