# Как написать путь к элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Есть фрагмент кода, не пойму как прописать путь к

```
<li><a href="#sheldure">расписания туров</a></li>
```

через jQuery, чтобы добавить анимацию. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```html
<div class="col-sm-7 main_nav">
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">методология</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sheldure">расписания туров</a></li>
                <li><a href="#include">что входит</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hotels">отели</a></li>
                <li><a href="#personal">тренера</a></li>
                <li><a href="#steps">этапы</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
```

Comment: если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам должно это подойти - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/379099/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83

Answer (score 1):

Если разметку трогать нельзя, то через селекторы:

- `.main_nav li:nth-child(2) a`
- `.main_nav a[href='#sheldure']`

Если можно, то просто задайте класс `<a href="#sheldure" class="sheldure"></a>`, тогда будет
 - `.main_nav . sheldure`

```js
$(".main_nav li:nth-child(2) a").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-7 main_nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">методология</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sheldure">расписания туров</a></li>
      <li><a href="#include">что входит</a></li>
      <li><a href="#hotels">отели</a></li>
      <li><a href="#personal">тренера</a></li>
      <li><a href="#steps">этапы</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".main_nav a[href='#sheldure']").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-7 main_nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">методология</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sheldure">расписания туров</a></li>
      <li><a href="#include">что входит</a></li>
      <li><a href="#hotels">отели</a></li>
      <li><a href="#personal">тренера</a></li>
      <li><a href="#steps">этапы</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```